# Node.js Override a class function of a module

Tags: node.js

How can I override the upload method of the S3 class that I import from the "aws-sdk" module in all the project file?

```
import {S3} from "aws-sdk";
const s3 = new S3({
    region: "us-east-1"
});
s3.upload({
    Bucket: "bucket",
    Key: "file",
    Body: "content",
    ACL: "private"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
    S3.prototype.upload = (params: S3.Types.PutObjectRequest, options?: ManagedUpload.ManagedUploadOptions) => {
           // Custom
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, you can override a class in a module by simply reassigning the value of the class name in the module's exports object.

For example, let's say you have a module called `myModule.js` with a class called `MyClass`:

```js
// myModule.js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log("MyClass constructor called");
  }

  myMethod() {
    console.log("MyClass method called");
  }
}

module.exports = {
  MyClass: MyClass,
};
```

To override `MyClass`, you can simply reassign the value of `MyClass` in your application code:

```js
// app.js
const myModule = require("./myModule");

class MySubClass extends myModule.MyClass {
  myMethod() {
    console.log("MySubClass method called");
  }
}

myModule.MyClass = MySubClass;

const myObj = new myModule.MyClass();
myObj.myMethod(); // Output: "MySubClass method called"
```

In the example above, we've defined a subclass `MySubClass` that extends `MyClass`, and then we've reassigned `MyClass` in the `myModule` module to be `MySubClass`. Now, when we create an instance of `MyClass` using `new myModule.MyClass()`, we actually get an instance of `MySubClass`, which overrides the `myMethod()` method to log a different message.

Why is `prototype` not interesting? Because with `prototype`, `this` doesn't work. And I can't explain why ^^"

Other example :

```js
const express = require('express');
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');

const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid');
const realm = require('peer/dist/src/models/realm');

const app = express();

app.enable('trust proxy');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});

class NewRealm extends realm.Realm {
  generateClientId() {
    let size = 4;
    let clientId = uuidV4().substring(0, size);
    while (this.getClientById(clientId)) {
      clientId = uuidV4().substring(0, size);
      size++;
    }
    return clientId;
  }
}

realm.Realm = NewRealm;

const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
  path: '/'
});

app.use('/peer', peerServer);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide explanations on your answer and not just block of code.

Comment: Done :) (thx chat gpt)
input > nodejs override class in module